# Adding $.put to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, put

Used specs: HTML5, Javascript

My question is as follows,
I am trying to make a put request to the api from Phillips HUE and I found the following method of adding $.put to Jquery:

```
$.put = function(url, data, callback, type){

 if ( $.isFunction(data) ){
    type = type || callback,
    callback = data,
    data = {}
  }

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    success: callback,
    data: data,
    contentType: type
  });
}
```

My javascript file will get multiple methods and I want to know where I have to add this code so it will work in all my methods. Can I make a method that runs before all others and adds $.put to my JQuery for all methods or do I have to put this block of code inside every method?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Greetings,
Chiel

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Thank you Jared for the response, As you might have figured I am quite new to jquery and I still have one question. Where do I have to put the code to create the plugin? Do I just add it at the top of my js file and it is useable in every piece of code under it?

Comment: Basically, you load the jQuery js file (`script src=jquery-path...`), then you load your plugins, which call into jQuery. This can be done in a number of ways, but I recommend placing one plugin per file and naming it appropriately. If you have more than a couple, consider [module loading](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/), although that's "somewhat" advanced compared to where you're probably at.

Comment: I recommend reading that module loading link anyway; Addy Osmani is a noted expert on Javascript application design and architecture and in the long-run, you're better off being at least familiar with what he proposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to OP's comment:

To include a custom jQuery plugin, simply:

1. Include jQuery
2. Include your plugin
3. Your code

Here's an actual code example:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="put.js"></script>
<script src="yourcode.js"></script>
```

Comment: but I'm using a seperate js file

Comment: @nfnneil - The pattern is "load library, load library plugins, load library/plugin-dependent code". Whether the plugins are defined as modules (good), individual files (ok for a couple)/one file (if built/cached from separate files, good) or inline (generally, not good, it's a plugin!), this is the pattern.